# can't read from SQlite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, nullpointerexception

My App crashes on starting the log shows that the error is when i try to get readable database , 
it seems that i got problems with context but i don't know what to do i've done much searching and tried many things .

i will post my classes and log .

My Fragment Class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.data.DbOpenHelper;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

public final String API_KEY = "b932ba435fc93a5944938fe9d44cd198";
public final String BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=&api_key=";


ArrayList<movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();
movieAdapter adapter;
GridView gridview;

DbOpenHelper dbHelper;


public MainFragment() {
    getDataFromDB();
}


public MainFragment(String SortBy) {
    new FetchDataFromApi(SortBy).execute();
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    dbHelper = new DbOpenHelper(getActivity());
    gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    return view;
}


class FetchDataFromApi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    String SORT_CATEGORY;

    FetchDataFromApi(String paramUrl) {
        SORT_CATEGORY = paramUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            Uri uriBuilder = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter("sort_by", SORT_CATEGORY)
                    .appendQueryParameter("api_key", API_KEY)
                    .build();
            URL url = new URL(uriBuilder.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            String response = sb.toString();
            ParseJsonData(response);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        adapter = new movieAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.movie_item, movies);
        gridview.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                PassDataToDetailedActivity(position);
            }
        });
    }


    private void ParseJsonData(String response) throws JSONException {
        String PosterBaseUrl = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/";
        String LargePoster = "w185";
        String SmallPoster = "";
        final String RESULTS = "results";
        final String ORIGINAL_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String OVERVIEW = "overview";
        final String RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        final String POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
        final String POPULARITY = "popularity";


        JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(response);
        Log.v("Json", response);
        JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

        for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            String title = object.getString(ORIGINAL_TITLE);
            String releaseDate = object.getString(RELEASE_DATE);
            String overView = object.getString(OVERVIEW);
            String voteAverage = object.getString(VOTE_AVERAGE);
            String popularity = object.getString(POPULARITY);
            String posterPath = object.getString(POSTER_PATH);

            String MaxPoster = PosterBaseUrl + LargePoster + posterPath;
            String MinPoster = PosterBaseUrl + SmallPoster + posterPath;

            movie m = new movie();
            m.setTitle(title);
            m.setReleaseDate(releaseDate);
            m.setOverView(overView);
            m.setVoteAverage(voteAverage);
            m.setPopularity(popularity);
            m.setLargePoster(MaxPoster);
            m.setMinPoster(MinPoster);

            movies.add(m);
        }
    }
}

private void PassDataToDetailedActivity(int position) {
    String title = movies.get(position).getTitle();
    String releaseDate = movies.get(position).getReleaseDate();
    String overView = movies.get(position).getOverView();
    String voteAverage = movies.get(position).getVoteAverage();
    String popularity = movies.get(position).getPopularity();
    String MaxPoster = movies.get(position).getLargePoster();
    String MinPoster = movies.get(position).getMinPoster();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailedActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("title", title);
    intent.putExtra("releaseDate", releaseDate);
    intent.putExtra("overView", overView);
    intent.putExtra("voteAverage", voteAverage);
    intent.putExtra("popularity", popularity);
    intent.putExtra("", MaxPoster);
    intent.putExtra("MinPoster", MinPoster);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void getDataFromDB() {
  \\ the problem is here
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
    String PosterUrl;
    ArrayList<String> list= new ArrayList<>();


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DbOpenHelper.TABLE_NAME ,null );
    if (cursor .moveToFirst()) {
    do{PosterUrl = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DbOpenHelper.FeedEntry.KEY_LARGE_POSTER_URL));

            list.add(PosterUrl);}

        while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false); {

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Log.v("List",(list.get(i)).toString());
    }

    Log.v("hello", "its working");

}
```

}

My DbHelper Class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

  /**
  * Created by ahmed on 12/17/2015.
  */
public class DbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "fav.db";

// Table name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Data";

// Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";


public static abstract class FeedEntry implements BaseColumns {

    public static final String KEY_LARGE_POSTER_URL = "largePoster";
    public static final String KEY_MINI_POSTER_URL = "minPoster";
    public static final String KEY_MOVIE_NAME = "movieName";
    public static final String KEY_RELEASE_DATE = "releaseDate";
    public static final String KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE = "vote_average";
    public static final String KEY_OVERVIEW = "overview";

}

public DbOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
            + KEY_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FeedEntry.KEY_LARGE_POSTER_URL + " TEXT,"
            + FeedEntry.KEY_MINI_POSTER_URL + " TEXT, "
            + FeedEntry.KEY_MOVIE_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + FeedEntry.KEY_RELEASE_DATE+" TEXT,"
            + FeedEntry.KEY_OVERVIEW+" TEXT,"
            + FeedEntry.KEY_VOTE_AVERAGE+" TEXT,"
            + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_FAVORITES_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}
}
```

My log

```
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime: Process:         com.example.ahmed.popularmovies, PID: 12140
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ahmed.popularmovies/com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:176)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6005)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:176) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.data.DbOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainFragment.getDataFromDB(MainFragment.java:194)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainFragment.<init>(MainFragment.java:49)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1572)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:423)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:398)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2275)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:111)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:314)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityHoneycomb.java:31)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:79)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.ahmed.popularmovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6005) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2446) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:176)     
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1437) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955) 
12-18 01:44:36.915 12140-12140/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

`

Comment: `Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class fragment`
maybe the error is on your activity

Comment: @vspallas this error only shows when i add the line i commented in my class with "the problem is here" if i remove it the app doesn't crash and works well so the problem happens bcuz of getting the database due to nullpointerExcepton

Comment: ok then try not to call the `getDataFromDB();` on the constructor but on the `onCreateView` below the `gridview`.

Comment: @vspallas the nullpointerException is now gone dude thank you ^^

Answer (score 0):

In your zero-argument fragment constructor, you are calling `getDataFromDB()`. In there, you are calling `getReadableDatabase()` on `dbHelper`. You have not initialized `dbHelper`, in part because you have no way to do so at this point. Hence, you crash with a `NullPointerException`.

First, do not implement constructors on fragments. I do not even recommend that for experts, let alone people new to Android and Java. The default zero-argument constructor that you get automatically will suffice for Android's needs. Do all your work elsewhere, driven by the fragment lifecycle methods (e.g., `onCreate()`).

Second, do database I/O (or any I/O) on background threads. Had you followed this rule, at least you would not have tried to do database I/O in a method invoked from a constructor, even if you ignored my first rule.

In order to use `SQLiteOpenHelper`, you need to create an instance of it. You are doing that in `onCreateView()`, which is fine. However, that means that you cannot attempt to use that instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` until `onCreateView()` has been called, or at least until that line of code has been executed.

Comment: i made the db work in asynctask which has made it much more easier as it doesn't block the ui so the error in MainActivity doesn't show ,,
I will see about the constructors later but the whole problem now is the NullPointerException

Comment: There are 2 things to prevent this error you can initialize dbHalper in constructor or you can call getDataFromDB(); in your onCreateView method to .